# How to access Outlook IMAP server using OAuth tokens retrieved from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: oauth, outlook, imap, microsoft-graph-api, rebex

We use Rebex to access mails of outlook account using OAuth tokens retrieved from login live API.
From last week outlook IMAP server returns "NO Authenticate failed" error code.
We update the token retrieval to Microsoft Graph APIs. Even then IMAP responds similarly.

Geeks support is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Arun. S

Comment: Why do you think an IMAP account would have any integration with the Graph APIs? They only work with Office 365 mailboxes

Comment: Graph API here i meant is access token retrieved from latest MS graph REST api.

Comment: The Graph API has nothing to do with IMAP. Can you please clarify why you are trying to use a Graph token to authenticate an IMAP connection? What kind of email account are you connecting to IMAP with?

Comment: We create access_token using login live api and try connecting imap-mail.outlook.com server using Rebex API. We use wl.imap scope too. But outlook server always returning authenticate failed(NO) error. With the same token we could login outlook smtp server. I hope now you got an idea of my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how IMAP fits into Graph authentication.

Comment: @ Eric Legault - I don't think it does. Unless Office 365 uses an IMAP4 standard extension that I am not aware of, I don't think it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful now , OAuth IMAP Auth support ... didn't used to work, but should now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth